# Subpixel positioning/rendering of views on Android

Tags: android

On Android 3.0 and above it's possible to specify the absolute position of a View using the setX / setY methods (or setTranslationX / setTranslationY). These methods take a float parameter.

While it's possible to specify the position of a view in subpixel coordinates, it seems that Android won't actually render the View using the fractional part of the coordinates, at least not by default.

This is different from the behavior on iOS, which can be seen in the image below (scaled up 400%):

[image: example]

Here I've added two UIImageViews (iOS) / ImageViews (Android). The upper one is positioned using whole integer coordinates, while the bottom one is positioned using half-pixel coordinates. On Android the View is clearly snapped to the nearest integer coordinates before rendering. Is it possible to get the same behavior as on iOS?

I'll admit that in this specific example Android gives the best visual quality. But my motivation for trying to enable subpixel rendering is to achieve smoother animations (when translating a view between two coordinates). Especially for slow animations on low/medium DPI-devices it's quite noticeable that the View is always snapped to the nearest integer coordinate during the animation. On iOS animations like this always appear silky smooth.

This is for a game by the way. It's so simple graphically that I'd like to avoid using OpenGL if possible, but I'm not willing to give up the silky smooth 60fps animations I can get on iOS.

Answer (score 3):

Since Android is based on java rendering hint could be adjusted for the graphics context. This might impose major impact on graphics performance.